Find the cardinality of $A \cup B$
Let the sets $A=\{\frac{1}{1\times 2} , \frac{1}{2\times 3}, ... , \frac{1}{2021\times 2022}\}, B=\{ \frac{1}{2\times 4}, \frac{1}{3\times 5}, ..., \frac{1}{2020\times 2022}\}$. Find the cardinality of  $A \cup B$.
Even thought this reminds me of the formula $\frac{k}{n(n+k)}=\frac{1}{n}- \frac{1}{n+k}$, I don't think this might help, because we don't have a sum
After some brute force and using some apps, I got to the fact that  the cardinality of  $A \cup B$ is 4040 so all the elements are distinct.
I this correct?

Clearly, the answer is $2$.

You figured the cardinality before determining the elements were distinct? and used the cardinality being what it was to determing the elements were distinct?  Not the other way around?  How that work?  And what's an "app" in this context?  Which app?

... And, I'll also repeat what others point out.  $A$ and $B$ each have only one element.  It easy to see $\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{23}+ ... + \frac{1}{20212022}\ne \frac{1}{24}+ \frac{1}{35}+ ...+ \frac{1}{20202022}$.  So it is very clear $A\cup B={\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{23}+ ... + \frac{1}{20212022}, \frac{1}{24}+ \frac{1}{35}+ ...+ \frac{1}{20202022}}$ and so the cardinality is $2$.  ... you know. You don't have to figure out what the values of the sums are. No-one is asking for that and it is not required.

@AnotherUser Sorry for the misspeling i edited my post

@fleablood Sorry for the mispelling i edited my post

@DaveL.Renfro I added this because there are sets in the problem, sorry I will eliminate the tag if its not right

$A=\{a_i\mid1\le i\le 2021\}$ and $B=\{b_j\mid2\le j\le 2020\}$, where
$a_i=\frac1{i(i+1)}$ and $b_j=\frac1{j(j+2)}$.
$$a_{2021}<b_{2020}<a_{2020}<b_{2019}<a_{2019}<\dots<b_2<a_2<a_1$$
hence $A,B$ are disjoint, so $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|=2021+2019=4040$.

Notice that $x\mapsto x(x+2)$ is increasing on $\mathbb R^+$
Therefore on positive integers $p(p+2)=n(n+1)$ has at most $1$ solution for a given $n$.
But $\begin{cases}n(n+2)>n(n+1)&\text{ so } p<n\\
(n-1)(n+1)=n^2-1<n^2+n=n(n+1)&\text{ so }p>n-1\end{cases}$
Since $p,n$ integers, such a $p$ doesn't exists.
As a consequence all elements in $A$ are different from all elements in $B$ and we have $\#(A\cup B)=\#A+\#B=(2021-1+1)+(2020-2+1)=4040$
